# discrete math and prove

Tags: discrete-mathematics

if that happens :
[image]

show:[image]

I say in advance my try may be total waste of time

$(A\cap B)\backslash C=A\cap B \cap C^c $

$x∈A  \ , \ x∈B \ and  \ x∉c $

$AΔBΔC = (A\backslash B)\cup(B\backslash A)\backslash C \cup C \backslash(A\backslash B)\cup(B\backslash A) $

$ C\backslash(A\backslash B) => x∈c  \  $

and thats contradiction

Comment: 6 questions more or less of the same type in 24 hours: take time to breath... It is not forbidden but I think that it's not a good use of this site.

Comment: not good use? why is that? this place is source of information nobody asked you to answer the question

Comment: I don't want to polemicate. Only a remark: your questions are : "can you check that what I have done is right". You cannot work in mathematics for a long time like this...

Comment: so how exactly should i know if i`m right? just keep it inside and hope for it because some guy thinks its too much to ask for help in math forum?

Comment: It's a question of gaining confidence into yourself, asking to fellows, etc... Once again, feel free to ask again and again the same type of question if A=B then C=D... No problem.

Comment: ok noted,and sorry that my questions not on your level,im just starting hope in the future i can challenge you more